# amp command not found

Tags: android, macos, facebook, ampersand

I am trying to generate the key hash for running Facebook android samples. I am using this command -

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore &amp;#126;/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

as given in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

But when I am running this command in my mac terminal, it says

> amp: command not found

I have tried replacing amp; with & but it still doesn't work. When I replace remove amp; it says

> Command option -keystore needs an argument.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the workaround for the "amp command not found" error but I found one for running the samples.

I downloaded the Facebook-sdk-master from github and then imported. Then I changed the package name of each sample app and changed the app id. Basically I converted it to make it seem my own application.

After this, I am able to run the samples